# How can I unit test for a stack overflow in my factorial function?

Tags: scheme, racket, factorial

I made a factorial function in Racket, which needs to be unit tested for passing  passing a very large number that would catch an overflow exception. If the exception is caught, the test should pass, and vice versa. Here is my code.

```
#lang racket

(provide recursive_factorial)
(provide tail_factorial)


(define (recursive_factorial number)
 (cond [(= 0 number) 1]
       [(negative? number) (raise-argument-error 'recursive_factorial "negative?" number)]
       [(*  number (recursive_factorial (- number 1)))]))


(define (tail_factorial number accumulator)

 (cond[( = number 0 ) accumulator]
      [(negative? number) accumulator (raise-argument-error 'tail_factorial  "negative?" number accumulator)]
      [(tail_factorial (- number 1) (* accumulator number ))]
      ))
```

And here is my attempt to unit test it.

```
(check-not-exn (λ () (recursive_factorial(100000000)))"stack overflow")
 (check-not-exn (λ () (tail_factorial(100000000)))"stack overflow")
```

With much help I was able to get a negative condition to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Racket doesn't have stack overflows (see http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Lists__Iteration__and_Recursion.html#%28part._.Recursion_versus_.Iteration%29); you won't get an error until you exhaust all of the memory available to Racket (and then the Racket VM will probably just quit).

Comment: @RyanCulpepper so is there no way to unit test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns `-1` when `number` is negative. So shouldn't the test be:

```
(check-equal? (recursive_factorial -4) -1)
```

UPDATE

How about:

```
 #lang racket
 (provide recursive_factorial)
 (define (recursive_factorial number)
  (cond [(= 0 number)       1]
        [(negative? number) (error 'recursive_factorial
                                   "Cannot pass a negative number")]
        [else               (*  number (recursive_factorial (- number 1)))]))
```

Comment: actually i need it to somehow not return-1. Instead tell me that the call is invalid.

Comment: @user6800688 Added new suggestion.

Comment: That works great! I actually was able to figure it out by raising an exception and then using (check-exn) to get it to work

Comment: Although I am also trying to get an out-of-memory exception to work. I have a tail recursion function as well. And I want to pass a huge number like 50000 in both the recursive and tail recursive. One should throw an exception... the other shouldn't. How can I do this?